# STM32F4 Bootloader to talk to SWIO

Tags: stm32, bootloader

Is there a way for our custom bootloader to communicate with SWD pins. I am asking this because if we want to put the code into a particular memory space while using SWD then we will need to use a custom bootloader. If there is any relevant post then its link will be useful. Any leads will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: What protocol you want to communicate over SWD pins? Because if you already use SWD pins for SWD, you usually use SWD protocol to begin with, so you don't need any custom bootloader or protocol. What would your custom bootloader do? Why not use the standard factory bootloader?

Comment: The standard factory bootloader puts the image in a fixed place as far as i know. I want to load the image in external flash actually and then run the code from there. I could do that using USART, DFU etc. But I wanted to do it through SWD.

Comment: That is a different problem. You can use SWD for anything. Even programming the internal flash requires the MCU to be loaded with program (flash program stub) that knows how to write the internal flash. What you seem to want is to upload a custom flash program stub so that uploaded binary data is programmed to external flash instead of internal flash.

Comment: Bootloaders can also do that. its just that i wanted to know if we can communicate using SWD protocol on the application layer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is already quite clear. I am not sure why someone would report it vague to let bot reply like this. Ciao already kind of shared a related problem.

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there a way for our custom bootloader to communicate with SWD pins?

Secondary boot loaders can be easily written.

I don't know if there's a way to overwrite the primary boot loader which is usually protected.

I don't know if there's a way to program and gain control of the SWD/JTAG interface once you are in the secondary boot loader.

> > to put the code into a particular memory space

Maybe I'm missing something. Compilers and linkers allow you to put code or pieces of code anywhere in the address space.

---

Programming external flash memories and reading/writing CPU's internal registers through the JTAG and SWD interfaces is possible.

You might want to read Segger's J-Link specifications.

Ciao

Comment: Link-only answers are useless. Especially when the people on that forum seem to be confused and wrong. You don't anyway program the flash directly through SWD. You upload a flasher stub into RAM and then you load data to RAM and call the stub to program data from RAM to flash.

Comment: This kind of relates to what i am asking though not 100% aligned.

Comment: But it's the other way around. The software running on the MCU can not and does not take control of the SWD interface. It's the PC that takes control of the MCU regardless of if the MCU core is running any code or held in reset.